# Homogenous polynomials and irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Hi i'm trying to do an exercise of algebra and i'm stuck. Here it goes

> Let $A$ be a factorial ring, $ F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ two non-zero polynomials of $A[X_1,\cdots ,X_k](k\in \mathbb{N}^{*})$, homogenous of degree  $n$ and  $n+1$,respectively,$(n\in \mathbb{N})$ and $F=F_n+F_{n+1}$.

> Show that, for any factorization $F=GH$, of the polynomials $G$ or $H$ is homogenous

> Prove that $F$ is irreducible if $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ are relatively prime.

> Show the reciprocal: if $F$ is irreducible then $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$ are relatively prime.

For the first one i wanted to say :

Suppose we have a factorization $F=GH$ in $A[X_1, \cdots , X_k,T]$ then,
\begin{align*}
F(TX_1, \cdots , TX_k)&=F_n(TX_1, \cdots , TX_k)+F_{n+1}(TX_1, \cdots , TX_k) \\
&=T^nF_n(X_1, \cdots , X_k)+T^{n+1} F_{n+1}(X_1, \cdots , X_k) \text{ by homogeneity } \\
&=T^n((F_n(X_1, \cdots , X_k)+T^{1} F_{n+1}(X_1, \cdots , X_k)) \\
&=G(TX_1, \cdots , TX_k)H (TX_1, \cdots , TX_k)
\end{align*}
And for exemple we take $G(TX_1, \cdots , TX_k)=T^nG(X_1, \cdots , X_k)=T^n$ which is homogenous of degree n. Since $G$ is homogenous in $A[X_1, \cdots , X_k,T]$ from the following we know that $G $ will be homogenous of degree $n$ in $A[X_1, \cdots , X_k]$.

Is this correct ? For the others i would greatly appreciate any hints/solution/partial solutions to start ! I'm guessing we have to use the property of the ring $A$ but i can't figure out how.

Thank you for your time !

Comment: No, it is not correct. The last part is trivial.

Comment: Any hints on how to do the question then please?